# Card probability for more complex hands

Tags: probability, card-games

My friends and I were playing a game -- as part of this game you can draw cards to gain a benefit. Now, over the course of this we got into a debate over the probability of various things occurring.

What led to the debate was the game listed drawing an Ace as a lower benefit than drawing a pair.

Let me explain the rules and then I'll get into what I did and what problem I am having.

The rules are that you may draw a minimum of 6 cards (up to a maximum of around 12). How many cards you specifically may draw are dependent upon other variables. It is not something you *choose* as much as it is predetermined. Once you draw your allotted cards you make the best hand you can with 5 of the cards (any 5 of the cards you drew).

The listed hands you can make are here: https://pastebin.com/jkRF9jEf

Now for the probabilities. I decided the approach I would take is pretty standard (1 minus the probability of not getting the hand to see getting at least 1).

For the Ace, I knew it would be $\frac{4}{54}$ (Jokers are included and count as wildcards but have a penalty for using). However, each card you draw would reduce the total cards remaining and as such it would be $\frac{4}{54-x}$ where $x$ is the number of cards drawn. Taking the probability of it not happening would be $1-\frac{54-4-x}{54-x}$ or $1-\frac{50-x}{54-x}$. Again, $x$ is the number of cards drawn. However, that would be the probability of drawing an ace on the next draw after drawing $x$ cards. I'm pretty sure you're suppose to take it to the power of the number of trials which would make it $1-(\frac{50-x}{54-x})^x$ and this would be the probability if you're going to draw $x$ cards that **at least 1** would be an Ace.

For pairs I took a similar approach:
$1-(\frac{54-4x}{54-x})^x$

Now, I'm not entirely sure that is correct. I remember from back when I took statistics something about ${n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ but that is giving very different results. I tried using $1-\prod_{n=1}^x{\frac{50-n}{54-n}}$ for both pairs and Aces but this is giving even more different results.

Further, I wanted to apply this to the more complex hands listed in the pastebin but am lost as to how to approach them.

Thus, my question: What am I doing wrong and how can I apply the right method to the more complex hands?

As for why I think none of these approaches are correct or that I implemented them incorrectly:

If we draw 2 cards, the probability of getting at least 1 Ace would be

$(\frac{4}{54})(\frac{3}{53})+(\frac{4}{54})(\frac{50}{53})+(\frac{50}{54})(\frac{4}{53})$

Which would be 2 Aces, no Ace and 1 Ace, 1 Ace and no Ace. The probability of getting *at least* 1 Ace would then be approximately 0.144 but none of the mentioned methods actually produce that result.

Additional update: It would appear I've solved it for the first two (Aces and pairs).

For Aces: $1-\prod_{n=1}^{x-1}{\frac{50-(n-1)}{54-(n-1)}}$

For pairs: $1-\prod_{n=1}^{x-1}{\frac{54-4n}{54-n}}$

For Jacks or better I'm struggling. If you were drawing 1 card the probability would be zero. If you're drawing two cards it would be, I think, $4(\frac{16}{54})(\frac{3}{53})$ because you'd have to get 1 of the four cards (Ace, Jack, Queen, King), then you would have to draw 1 of the remaining 3 cards for the first card drawn but there are 4 ways this could play out (draw Ace first, draw King first, draw Queen first, draw Jack first). However, after that, I'm not sure how it would play out.